Eigenvalue of integral operator with weak polar kernel
There is linear integral operator $A\phi=\mu \int_\Omega |x-y|^{-1}\phi(y)dy$, $x,y \in R^3$, $diam(\Omega)<R_\Omega=const$. What are system of eigenvalues ($\lambda_k=1/\mu_k$) and eigenfunctions $\phi_k (x)\in L^2(\Omega)$ for this operator? I suppose $\phi_k =\exp(ikx)$, $k=0,1,...$, but with some normalization. Am I right? But $\lambda_0 \to \infty$ in this case... Help me, please!
